# json_encode() rejects two MySQL columns

Tags: php, mysql, json, angularjs

I'm trying to display data in HTML page by using PHP and AngularJS. Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin", "webstore");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$output = array();
$json = array();
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM products');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $output = array(
        'id'=>$row['id'],
        'code'=>$row['product_code'],
        'image'=>$row['product_image'],
        'price'=>$row['price']
        
    );

  array_push($json, $output);    

}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

and here's the code from controller.js

```
controller('MainController', function($scope,$http) {

    $http.get('prod.php').success(function(response){
        $scope.items = response;
        console.log(response);

    });
```

So everything is displaying nicely to my HTML page, but when I add to array

```
$row['name'] && $row['description']
```

`console.log(response)` is empty as well as `echo json_encode($json)`. However if I just write `print_r($json)`, it prints the right results.

So I don't have any clue why `json_encode()` does not accept those two columns. Any help would be nice.

#### UPDATE

So to be clear I tried to add `$row['name']` && `$row['description']` into `$output` array while I go trough the results from query. So it would be like this:

```
$output = array(
    'id'=>$row['id'],
    'code'=>$row['product_code'],
    'image'=>$row['product_image'],
    'price'=>$row['price'],
    'name'=>$row['name'],
    'description'=>$row['description']
);
```

But as I said, this did not work for some reason.

The structure of my database table is like following:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| id            | int(11) primary key |
| product_code  | varchar(50)         |
| name          | varchar(50)         |
| description   | text                |
| price         | double              |
| product_image | varchar(50)         |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: can you show the structure of your `product` database table? Also, can you show the code that adds the `$row['name']` and `$row['description']` into the response? That might help.

Comment: Where are you adding $row['name'] && $row['description'] also this will return a boolean.

Comment: what does json_last_error() results (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) tell you? If anything?

Comment: It prints "5", so it seems that it is JSON_ERROR_UTF8

Comment: Can you put your answer in the answer box provided? This is preferable to editing the answer into the question, as it remains in the "unanswered" pool.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by adding

```
mysqli_set_charset('utf8)
```

and now everything is displaying right:

```
<?php

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin", "webstore");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$output = array();
$json = array();
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM products');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $output = array(
        'id'=>$row['id'],
        'code'=>$row['product_code'],
        'image'=>$row['product_image'],
        'price'=>$row['price']

    );

    array_push($json, $output);   
}

mysqli_set_charset('utf8);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_set_charset('utf8)` has unmatched single quotes.